# How does Task.Factory.FromAsync work / behave?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm relatively new to C#, so please bear with me.

I am trying to understand how Task FromAsync works.

```
var task1 = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(Foo1, ...);  //what happens here? Is this 
called on a thread from threadpool?

SomeCode1(); // <- is this code executed in parallel with Foo1

task1.ContinueWith(Foo2,...);   //does this block the current thread until Foo1
 finishes? Shouldn't it act like a callback? If this whole code runs on a "normal"
thread does it block it? If this runs on a thread from a thread pool does it 
 release the thread until Foo1 finishes?

SomeCode2();
```

Thank you for your help, I'm really struggling with async programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FromAsync` provides a convenient mechanism which uses the `BeginXxx` and `EndXxx` methods of the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx) to create a `Task`.

The resulting `Task` will, by default, be executed on a thread pool thread (and your subsequent call to `SomeCode1()` will indeed execute on the current thread, in parallel to the `Task`).

The `ContinueWith` method on `Task` does indeed act rather like a callback, i.e. the delegate provided to this method will execute after the task has finished, also on *some* thread pool thread. It does *not* block the current thread.

Indeed, you should set up this continuation when creating the task, e.g.

```
var task1 = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(Foo1, ...).ContinueWith(Foo2,...);
```

For more general and detailed info on threading in .NET I thoroughly recommend reading a good text such as part V of [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045).

Comment: "The resulting Task will, by default, be executed on a thread pool thread" - only if the operation actually requires a thread to run. For example, I/O operations will use an I/O completion port rather than a thread. This scales better as threads are a limited and somewhat expensive resource.

Comment: @Allon: you make a valid point that, with an I/O bound operation the bulk of the work does _not_ take place on a thread pool thread, but even in this case, is it not that the _call_ to BeginXxx and the I/O completion port callback (which will call EndXxx) both happen on a threadpool thread?

Comment: The call to BeginXxx can be made from any thread, even the UI thread, since it doesn't block. The callback will be called on a ThreadPool thread, but newer programming models (such as [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) and Task/await) may run the callback/event/continuation on a specific thread, such as the UI thread, if the task was started from that thread. See the documentation on the `SynchronizationContext` class and the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` method.